# Why Admob revenue reset many times

Tags: admob

I have upload an app to apple store , which using admob ads. i don't know why my revenue reset many time per day, drop from 4$ to 0$, with more than 8,000 impression ( just 1 click recognized ).  (some time it show 2 click then reset again )  . My app just uploaded in 10 days

[image]

Comment: I find out the root cause, my app not link to apple store. but after more then 10 day admob can link to apple. since the revenue not reset

Answer (score 0):

Your users have the decision to click on the ad or not. Sometimes, your app gets lucky and has more users click on it. As a result, your daily revenue can fluctuate between zero and some small number. Those "resets" occur every day because the revenue per day, by definition, starts at zero at the start of every day. Why are you confused about this?